# Problem with finding extreme values with TI84

Tags: calculator, extreme-value-analysis

I'm trying to find the extreme values of a function with TI84 plus CE.

I have found the same instructions on several sites and in the manual. 
However, I don't get the correct resuluts.

Example: f: y = x² - 4
I enter the function.
I select 2nd + trace (to get the calc functions)
I selcect option 3: minimum
I see the graph and move the cursor to the left of the minimum and press enter.
I move the cursor to the right of the minimum and press enter.
I press enter again.
The result should be x=0  y=-4
The result I get is x=-2.069E-6  y=-4

I've tried with several functions and I get wrong results every time.
I'm obviously doing something wrong, but I have no idea what.

Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Comment: Accuracy problem only, I guess.

Comment: Computers/calculators aren't 100 percent precise. Rounding errors may occur when 1. the processor internally stores numerical values as floating numbers and 2. when the calculator displays the graph on its screen.